# Cocoa-pods breaking build Undefined symbols for architecture i386:

Tags: cocoapods

I am trying to install [this library](https://github.com/vesselio/ABTesting/blob/Studio/ABTestingVessel.podspec) using Cocoapods when i execute pod install it just start giving errors.

```
    Symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
```

But if just drag and drop this library it works fine. I verified FAT file too and its built for all slices.

```
    Architectures in the fat file: Vessel.framework/Vessel are: armv7 armv7s i386 x86_64 arm64
```